# Token class implementation with std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, variant-type, lexical-analysis

So I've been trying to implement a Token class in C++. At first I wanted to use a simple `enum class` to store the `Kind` of the Token.

But then I came across a problem. Some Tokens (such as keywords, identifiers, numeric literals, etc.) would need to store an external value along with their `Kind`, while others wouldn't. I tried to get around the problem by creating a struct for each Token Kind and then using an `std::variant` for the `Kind` type. Here's the code I ended up with:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class Token
{
  public:
    struct Num
    {
        std::int64_t val;
    };

    struct Float
    {
        double val;
    };

    struct String
    {
        std::string val;
    };

    struct Keyword
    {
        std::string val;
    };

    struct Identity
    {
        std::string val;
    };

    struct LParen
    {
    };
    struct RParen
    {
    };
    struct LBrace
    {
    };
    struct RBrace
    {
    };
    struct LBracket
    {
    };
    struct RBracket
    {
    };
    struct Semicolon
    {
    };
    struct Colon
    {
    };
    struct Dot
    {
    };

    struct Operator
    {
        enum class Name : std::uint_fast8_t
        {
            Add = 0,
            Sub,
            Mult,
            Div,
            Pow
        };

        Name val;
    };

    struct EndOfFile
    {
    };

    struct Invalid
    {
    };

    using Kind =
        std::variant<Num, Float, String, Keyword, Identity, LParen, RParen, LBrace, RBrace,
                     LBracket, RBracket, Semicolon, Colon, Dot, Operator, EndOfFile, Invalid>;

    struct Span
    {
        std::uint_fast64_t row;
        std::uint_fast64_t col;
    };

    Token() = delete;
    Token(Kind const& kind, Span span) : m_kind(kind), m_span(span) {}

    auto kind() const -> Kind { return m_kind; }
    auto span() const -> Span { return m_span; }

    auto isEOF() const -> bool { return std::holds_alternative<EndOfFile>(m_kind); }
    auto isValid() const -> bool { return !std::holds_alternative<Invalid>(m_kind); }

  private:
    Kind m_kind;
    Span m_span;
};
```

Is this a valid way to do what I originally intended to do? Or is it way too complicated and there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems great to me — a nice way to simulate algebraic data types in C++.

The only improvement I can think of:

```cpp
struct Operator
{
    enum class Name : std::uint_fast8_t
    {
        Add = 0,
        Sub,
        Mult,
        Div,
        Pow
    };

    Name val;
};
```

Why not make `Operator` itself an `enum class`?

I might consider changing

```cpp
Token(Kind const& kind, Span span) : m_kind(kind), m_span(span) {}
```

to

```cpp
template <typename T>
Token(T&& kind, Span span)
    : m_kind(std::forward<T>(kind)) // #include <utility>
    , m_span(span)
{
}
```

to avoid the overhead of constructing an extra `variant`.

---

The OP mentioned grouping the symbols together into an `enum class` in the comments.  Whether this is beneficial depends on how the symbols will be used.  It is easier to handle all the symbols together:

```cpp
enum class Symbol {
    LParen, RParen, LBrace, RBrace, LBracket, RBracket, Semicolon, Colon, Dot,
};

// ...

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Symbol symbol) {
    static const std::unordered_map<Symbol, char> table {
        { Symbol::LParen, '(' },
        { Symbol::RParen, ')' },
        // etc.
    };

    return os << table.at(symbol);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Token& token) {
    std::visit(Overloaded {
        // ...
        [&](Symbol symbol) { os << symbol; }, // uniform handling
        // ...
    }, token.kind);
    // ...
}
```

versus

```cpp
struct LParen {};
struct RParen {};
struct LBrace {};
struct RBrace {};
// etc.

// ...

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Token& token) {
    std::visit(Overloaded {
        // ...
        [&](LParen) { os << '('; },
        [&](RParen) { os << ')'; },
        [&](LBrace) { os << '{'; },
        [&](RBRace) { os << '}'; }, // manual handling
        // ...
    }, token.kind);
    // ...
}
```

But it is harder to check if a token is a given symbol:

```cpp
enum class Symbol {
    LParen, RParen, LBrace, RBrace, LBracket, RBracket, Semicolon, Colon, Dot,
};

// ...

bool is_symbol(const Token& token, Symbol symbol) {
    if (auto p = std::get_if<Symbol>(token)) {
        return *p == symbol;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

versus simply a call to `std::holds_alternative`.

The same applies to the operators.

Comment: Ah yeah, changing operator itself to an enum class is something I should do. Also, I don't quite get what you did with the constructor. I don't even know if it's possible to make a template constructor for a non-template class

Comment: @Famiu It is indeed possible - I edited the answer to clarify.  The difference here is that the argument is directly forwarded to the constructor of `std::variant`, whereas in your version, a temporary `std::variant` is constructed and then copied to `m_kind`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Do you think I should group all symbols together inside a symbols enum, or is it fine how it is?

Comment: @Famiu Ultimately, it depends on the usage pattern.  Grouping them together is beneficial when the code handles all symbols in a uniform manner, but it would be slightly more work (a helper function, that is) to check if a token is a specific symbol (`get_if` + `==`).

Comment: Does the same apply for the operators, then? Should I flatten them out as well or keep them as an enum?

Comment: @Famiu Yes - both have their advantages and drawbacks.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all that. I'm going to accept your answer